# Add workflow to SharePoint 2010 to delete pages older than a particular period

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am working on creating a SharePoint 2010 site. I want to create a workflow for wiki library content where in the content gets auto-deleted if it gets older than a particular period, say any page which is 6 months old. Also before deleting I would like to send an email to a group telling that auto-deletion will take place for so and so items.

How can do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This can be done out of the box with SharePoint 2010.  If you go to "Information Management Policy Settings" which you can set on the wiki page content type or override at the library level, this will let you do what you want.

You can setup different retention stages.  So you could have it kick off different actions at different stages.  The following actions are available for the stages you create.

- Move to Recycle Bin
- Permanently Delete
- Transfer to another location (won't work with pages)
- Start a workflow
- Skip to next stage
- Declare Record
- Delete previous drafts
- Delete all previous versions

[More information is available here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-apply-information-management-policies-HA101631505.aspx)